# Dialog Activity - Adding button click listeners

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I am trying to create an Activity which can be used like a dialog.
My Activity has a dialog theme, so it has the dialog feel.
In my layout I have added a TextView, to display a message, and three buttons (Positive, Negative, Neutral). The text message which is to be displayed is passed as an extra in the Intent. So are the Button names. I am hiding the button for which an empty string has been passed in the intent-extras. This almost implements the behaviour of dialog, except that I have no idea how to implement the button click listeners.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your layout in an XML file you can add something like `onClick="onMyButtonClick"` for your button, then in code you shall have

```
public void onMyButtonClick(View sender) { ... }
```

Alternatively you can have in your `onCreate()`

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });
```

I guess you will want to call `finish()` from your onCLickListener somewhere, perhaps together with `setResult()`

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple:
You shoud start you dialog via `startActivityForResult(Intent, requestCode);`
and override method onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) to get result of your dialog activity.

Each of your dialog button, must call `setResult()` and than finish it. and you will be back to main activity in method onActivityResult with resultCode and data if you passed them.

Comment: It will indeed solve my problem, but for that I need be be invoking the dialog activity from within another activity. You see my problem is that I do not have an Activity context.

Comment: And how do you plan start activity and where do you want to handle clicks?

Comment: I have the application context, I can start the activity from that. I want be able to handle clicks from where I invoked the Activity, doen't need to be a proper clicklistener, just some sort of a callback based on the button clicked.